# How to convert from java.util.Map<String, Long> to Scala immutable Map

Tags: java, scala, converters

I'm using Scala 2.11.12. I have a `java.util.Map<String, Long>`, which I'd like to convert to a Scala immutable `Map[String, Long]`. How do I do that?

I tried to use `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` as follows

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val scalaMap = response.jMap.asScala // this throws compile error Required  Map[scala.Predef.String, Long], but found mutable.Map[java.lang.String, java.long.Long]

val scalaMap = response.jMap.asScala.toMap // this now throws compile error required Long, but found java.long.Long
```

The issue seems to be that a Java `Long` is not the same as a Scala `Long`.

I see that there is a `Long2long` option, but how to use that here?

Comment: Try with `response.jMap.asScala.mapValues(Long.unbox).toMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that worked, thanks a LOT. Curious, as someone new to Scala, how do I even learn to do stuff like this?

Comment: `scala.Long` is not `java.lang.Long`. The compiler tries too hard to make you think otherwise with implicit boxing and unboxing. But when the values are inside a container, you have to trigger the conversion manually. - This is the kind of things you learn by experience.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, why are writing it as a comment and posting an answer?

Comment: @TomerShetah 1) because I was on the cellphone so I couldn't test the code to be correct. - 2) because, IMHO, a single line answer is not worth it. - 3) This is probably a duplicate, which I am too lazy to check and I do not want to be downvoted again for answering a duplicate.